# What should a normal fuel pressure reading look like?

Tags: fuel-system, focus

**Some quick background:**

While idling, my 2007 Ford Focus "revs" at about a 1-second cycle, you can hear the engine subtly go "wroom / wroom / wroom". It has issues with long crank times to start and sudden loss of power while driving.

**My question:**

I have recorded about a minute of the engine idling. You can see the fuel pressure cycle as the engine revs - as the fuel pressure goes up, the engine revs up, and then back down again.

What is a "normal" fuel pressure reading? Is the fuel pressure cycling like this indicative of a fuel system problem or something else?

**The data**

Here's the fuel pressure:

[image]

And here's the RPMs overlaid on them. Note that they diverge towards the end - I'm not sure this is correct; while recording it I was watching the pressure chart and the sound of the engine correlated exactly with the pressure, so I'm wondering if the drift is a delay in the recording.. not sure.

[image]

In case that's not helpful, here's the complete reading of all the metrics: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AahZZ-ru4P5d3NkOs5fiPIgjKXZeIMLhq7RFlKQYxj8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So a fuel pressure reading of 40 +/- 1.5, don't really see an issue there as 1.5 is less than 4% of 40... If the reading was fluctuating 20% or30% then there may be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doesn't sound like a fuel issue to me.  Electric fuel pumps and regulators rarely just lose pressure.  They fail altogether.  I realize there isn't much data to go on here, but do you not have any trouble codes?  Fuel system out of range would trip one.  I am leaning more towards something causing extra air into the system such as a cracked vacuum hose, or perhaps the MAF is lying.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, check for a dirty throttle plate.

Comment: Since the question was if this fuel pressure looks correct, marking this as solved since you're answering that, thank you!

On follow-on exploration: I did another run recording the fuel trim, MAF and O2. Long term fuel trim trends around 0-3%, avg. about +2.5%.. That doesn't seem totally out of the ballpark, but does seem to imply it's running lean?

I had a vacuum leak on the PCV hose a while back, dried-out O-rings, so it would make sense if other vacuum parts are worn out..

Comment: well it's funny.  In theory the oxygen sensor should detect lean also and pump in more gas.  I would have a hydrocarbon test done to see if you are actually running lean.